# Reading a variable in UNIX SCRIPT having more than 255 characters

Tags: unix

I am facing an issue while passing a `variable(KEY)` where its value is more than 255 characters.
In number of places in the script I need to pass this `KEY`, but its not accepting it.

Please suggest what I should be doing.

In a curl command i need to pass a variable as `$KEY_TOKEN`, where `KEY_TOKEN`'s value looks like below

`SessionToken: YKtEZXwIAj8DQC/Ula5ns5zgnTyJ3F1d5z/Wlbn+65XEBXbzp95z+keE4PwYs+d1nzb0oaq2Fetg39xs2BgyqD0zLVa0dw8sxSdc5pBtAeOha3VXAR11zs9thE5j2RS7T0aU7/Q1wJu4ERBOuRUbXa1Kkr9/1rq+D07X9U/gNncN9uYEqkPK5oOUuH+b1exEqxcXVXRPaWXNbpI23bmarU90bL4ogRRTV7ov4R/Da8e9cclEqw7AHG/1rEdJ0ou6zg8TDMp9rk1wgjP/EFo8gbbYkEuOXYzFwHvrKCsKQtYBimXoJ2V4VRkSKtL8JNC/An4DB7WC8tHrqdIddDzjb9edjEPsWxNn32KBtLL8zjIgOI8HvVGBUZ4LNH1+aUJFs9terJ1XXnESJT9H4S+pbw==`

Comment: So what is the problem? BASH variables can by much longer than that!

Comment: It's likely that your problem is somewhere else, so we'll need to see some [code that represents your problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: first i am sending the web-service request to generate a KEY_TOKEN. This is working fine. KEY_TOKEN is generated as given above.    In the next requests i need to pass this KEY_TOKEN as a variable ($KEY_TOKEN) rather passing its lengthy value. But its not accepting

Comment: Show much more code. I guess the problem is elsewhere. Do you have backslashes, quotes, or question marks in your strings? They might be processed by bash if you misuse quotations.

Comment: How are you passing the variable? Is it quoted? What's the exact error you are getting?

Comment: curl -v -X POST -D tmp.txt -H "Content-Type:text/plain" --data "$SECRET" -H "Accept:application/xml" -H "Connection:close" http://$BASE_URI/api/${PLATFORM}/authenticate
SESSION_TOKEN=`grep SessionToken tmp.txt`

# User Auth Request
curl -v -X POST -D tmp.txt -H "$SESSION_TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -H "Accept:application/xml" -H "Connection:close" --data "{ \"username\":\"$USER_NAME\",\"password\":\"$PASSWORD\", \"rememberMe\":\"false\"}" http://$BASE_URI/api/$PLATFORM/users/authenticate >> result.xml
AUTH_HEADER=`grep Authorization tmp.txt`

Comment: This is how i am passing ... first curl command gets me session token. and that session token i need to pass it to 2nd one as a variable